# leaflet.js maps not showing with custom host in laravel

Tags: laravel, leaflet

leaflet.js maps in my local laravel app not showing on custom host (ex: 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000), but if using localhost, maps shown. is there any solution for me?

(sorry for bad english)

[expecting in custom host run like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAMVu.png)

on localhost
[on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBeoH.png)

on custom host
[on custom host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41ryu.png)

Comment: Can you show us what you did, so that we can get context and give you insight into it.

Comment: Any errors in your browser's DevTools/console?

Comment: no error in browsers console @brombeer